# Why do Dataflow steps not start?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a linear three step Dataflow pipeline - for some reason the last step started, but the preceding two steps hung in `Not started` for a long time before I gave up and killed the job. I'm not sure what caused this, as this same pipeline had successfully run in the past, and I'm surprised it didn't show any errors in the logs as to what was preventing the first two steps from starting. What can cause such a situation and how can I prevent it from happening?

Comment: Was this a streaming pipeline? Did you observe any progress? Like element counts increasing, when you click on the steps on the Monitoring UI? What about the watermarks, did you observer them increasing?

Some causes of stuck pipelines.
(1) Sending too much data to the same key, after a GroupByKey (I.e. a very hot key). If you have any user code which can potentially block, i.e. make an RPC (2). (3) Do you use a BigQuery Sink, there are known issues with slow BQ exports.

Did it pass on a 2nd attempt?

Do you have the job id of the pipeline? We might be able to investigate more.

Comment: This was a batch pipeline. There was no progress, no element counts increased. (1) I tested running it on data that the job succeeded on in the past, so this shouldn't be it (2) No RPC (3) No BQ. I've attempted a few times without success. An example job id for one that I cancelled is 2018-05-12_18_04_14-1848949634103184693

Comment: Talked with someone - it may be an issue with the workers not starting - apparently our final step might not require workers as it is just writing to GCS

Comment: Figured it out, wasn't looking at correct logs, will post answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was happening because of an error in the worker start up. Certain Dataflow steps do not seem to require workers (e.g. writing to GCS), which is why that step was able to start - i.e. that step starting does not imply that workers are being created correctly. Worker start up is not displayed in the job logs by default - you need to click the link to `Stackdriver` in the job logs and then add `worker-startup` in the logs drop down in order to see any of those errors.